# ARIMA Model forecast not enough values for step error

Tags: pandas, arima, forecast

I am running an ARIMA method to forecast stock values, but i cannot get the forecast, since it forces the step to be 3.

```py
n = int(len(df)*0.8)
train = df.Close[:n]
test = df.Close[n:]
print(len(train))
print(len(test))
model = ARIMA(train, order=(6,1,3))
result = model.fit()
result.summary()
fc, se, conf = result.forecast(step = 30)
```

returns this error

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Untitled-1.ipynb Cell 44 in 1
----> 1 fc, se, conf = result.forecast(30)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

If I put in the step=3, it will return a float as the fc, but what im looking for is an array.